# Can anyone explain how to link a database value to a div

Tags: html, mysql, database

is there anyone that can just write down the basics for database knowledge? i want to link a database to my html page but have no knowledge about it

this is my html page and i want the div background linked to a databse value that when the value is true the background is green if false background is red, now it works with a button input that if pressed it change to the opposite color

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.default.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Grafiek</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Server Stats</h1>
<div id="maindiv">
    <div id="server1" class="serverstatus">
        <div id="cardheader">
            (servername1)
        </div>
        <div>
            Status:
        </div>

        <br>
        <div>
            Last Checked:
        </div>
        <div>
            Last Online:
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="toggleStatus(this)">yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="server2" class="serverstatus">
        <div id="cardheader">
            (servername2)
        </div>
        <div>
            Status:
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            Last Checked:
        </div>
        <div>
            Last Online:
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="toggleStatus(this)">yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="server3" class="serverstatus">
        <div id="cardheader">
            (servername3)
        </div>
        <div>
            Status:
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            Last Checked:
        </div>
        <div>
            Last Online:
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="toggleStatus(this)">yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>

    function toggleStatus(e) {
        var parentDiv = e.parentNode.parentNode;
        var bgColor = parentDiv.style.backgroundColor;

        if (bgColor == "darkred") {
            parentDiv.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        } else {
            parentDiv.style.backgroundColor = "darkred";
        }
    }


    // var green = false
    // function toggleStatus()
    // {
    //     if (green = !green)
    //     {
    //          $("#maindiv .serverstatus").each(function ()
    //         {
    //             $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    //         });
    //     }
    //     else
    //     {
    //         $("#maindiv .serverstatus").each(function ()
    //         {
    //             $(this).css("background-color", "#639919");
    //         });
    //     }
    // };

    // function updateStatus(){
    //     $("#maindiv .serverstatus").each(function(){
    //         $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    //     });
    // }
    //
    // $( document ).ready(function() {
    //     updateStatus();
    // });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use php and ajax, if ajax return true change color.

Comment: Databases works at the `Backend` of your host server, plain html is `Frontend parsed`, so you need some language (like PHP) that would talk to the `Backend`, get the `Database values` you need, and then produce a `Frontend` HTML with the values from the `Backend`.